# Removing the last item from a collection of instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code does not work due to line 4 (can't convert Foo into Array). How can fix it?

```
def index
  @foos = Foo.all 
  @latest_foo = Foo.last
  @remaining_foos = @foos - @latest_foo
end
```

Here's the reason why I'm doing this:

I have a database table with 5 foos. I want the first item in my view to be in a div titled "latest-foo".  I want all the remaining foos to go into divs whose class alternates between even and odd depending on their position in my list.

Someone asked a [similar question](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=17656) a while back on railsforum, but the approach was a little different. I guess I can use this solution but I'd like to see if there's a better, cleaner or more efficient way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array#pop` to do this quite easily:

```
@foos = Foo.all # assuming that they're sorted in the order you want
@latest_foo = @foos.pop
```

See: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000227